# Mo' Variables and solspace category ID

Tags: solspace, calendar-events

I've tried several variations of the following trying to render events that are in category 21 for logged in user groups 1 and 6. However, they still render if you're logged out (guest id 3). Any thoughts?

```
    {if '{logged_in_group_id}' == '1' OR '{logged_in_group_id}' =='6'}
{exp:calendar:cal
date_range_start="today"
show_months="6"
pad_short_weeks="n" 
category="20|21"
}

{if:else}
{exp:calendar:cal
date_range_start="today"
show_months="6"
pad_short_weeks="n" 
category="not 21"
}

{/if}
    <li>

            <h2><a href="/events/{url_title}/">{event_title} </a></h2>
            {event_summary}
       {categories}cat: {category_id}{/categories}
        {event_start_date format="%F %j, %Y"} {event_start_date format="%g:%i %A"} {if '{event_end_date format="%M %d, %Y %g:%i %A"}'} - {event_end_date format="%g:%i %A"}{/if}
    </li>

    {if no_results}
    <li>No Results</li>
    {/if}
{/exp:calendar:cal}
```

Comment: Do you really have only the opening `{exp:calendar:cal}` tag in the above advanced conditional?

Comment: I updated post to show the full loop